# how to set a picked image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I tried using this for picking and Saving Image->

```
File imageFile;

Future getImage(int type) async {
   PickedFile pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(
    source: type == 1 ? ImageSource.camera : 
  ImageSource.gallery,
      imageQuality: 50
);

if (pickedImage == null) return;

File tmpFile = File(pickedImage.path);
tmpFile = await tmpFile.copy(tmpFile.path);

   setState(() {
    imageFile = tmpFile;
      });
    }


 imageFile != null
              ? Image.file(
            imageFile,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
          )
              : Text("Pick up the image"),
```

But, Image is not saving. Nothing has been Displayed. What else I need to do?

Comment: Can you add a bare minimum working code snippet, so that someone can replicate the issue on their end and help you with a better specific solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is very ambiguous, it's very unclear where you are calling `getImage` and where you are setting the image.

I suppose you are not calling getImage() properly and not sure where you are using this `if (pickedImage == null) return;` it might be wrong.

Anyway, here's a proper explanation it should work.

- Declare your `getImage` method inside the Widget class.

```
Future<File> getImage(int type) async {
   PickedFile pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: type == 1 ? ImageSource.camera : 
      ImageSource.gallery,
      imageQuality: 50
    );
    return pickedImage;
  }
```

- Declare the `File` state variable in the sate class

```
File imageFile;
```

- Have a `Button` for the selecting action of the image in your widget.

```
...
   IconButton(
     icon: Icon(Icons.gallery),
     onPressed: () {}
   )
...
```

- call the `getImage` method and `setState` the result in the `onPressed` handler.

```
...
   IconButton(
     icon: Icon(Icons.gallery),
     onPressed: () async {
      final tmpFile = await getImage(1);
       
        setState(() {
          imageFile = tmpFile;
      });
   )
...
```

- Display your file in a widget

```
 imageFile != null
           ?Image.file(
            imageFile,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
          ): Text("Pick up the image"),
```